# Checking which object appears most times in a list c#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list

So i Have a temporary `ListObject` List used just to check the condition

```
class ListObject
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public void Convert(string str)
    {
        Key = str;
    }
}
```

and I'm writing a method supposed to check which name appears most times in another List of objects. The *`ListObject.Key`* gets the name assigned, while *`ListObject.Value`* stores the number of appearances. I want to check if the name was already stored from the List I'm holding the value in, and if yes, then increase the Value on the ListObject field which stores the name. 
The thing is that i have no idea how to point the field which should be increased. I would need something like `list[*index of the wanted name].Value += 1;` How am i supposed to point the index? And should I use KeyValue pair instead of my *`ListObject`* class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to re-invent a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`

```
var frequencyMap = new Dictionary<string,int>();
foreach(string item in itemList)
{
    if (!frequencyMap.ContainsKey(item))
        frequencyMap.Add(item, 0);

    frequencyMap[item] += 1;
}
```